# What is windows 10 like for the Pi 2?

Tags: windows, pi-2

[With MS support and all for the new Pi 2](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/featured/raspberrypi2support), what exactly can one expect from the windows 10 Pi version?

[it's being targeted at the "Maker" community](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/02/02/windows-10-coming-to-raspberry-pi-2/), for applications in the IoT space and home automation, and I doubt that any x86 programs will be able to be run on it, so what does that leave?

will Microsoft bring some apps from the RT (tablet) version of windows? (but those mostly depend on a touch screen, which isn't guaranteed)

is there a "beta" version or similar that's downloadable (similar to how the consumer preview is available for windows 10?) - if not, will there be anything (prior to the actual windows 10 launch, whenever that may be)?

I am particularly interested in anything "unique" or unavailable in the current Linux (raspbian and other) systems that run on the Pi that will be possible in windows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find out by downloading the IoT Preview <sup>(No direct links are allowed during Preview. Please sign up.)</sup>

> You need a Rasbperry Pi2 and atleast a 4GB SD Card.

- Sign up to [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/windowsembeddediot/SelfNomination.aspx?ProgramID=8558)
- Accept the "Surveys" if you wish to download
- Click on the Downloads tabs and download Windows 10 IoT Core

If you are using Windows 7 or 8.

- You need to [download the ADK Kit](http://click.xda-developers.com/api/click?format=go&jsonp=vglnk_143333998668012&key=f0a7f91912ae2b52e0700f73990eb321&libId=iagtk7yf01000n4o000DA46a6i30q&loc=http%3A%2F%2Fforum.xda-developers.com%2Fraspberry-pi%2Fgeneral%2Fflashing-windows-10-core-to-raspberry-t3097894&v=1&out=http%3A%2F%2Fgo.microsoft.com%2Ffwlink%2Fp%2F%3FLinkId%3D526740&ref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.uk%2F&title=Flashing%20Windows%2010%20Core%20to%20Raspberry%20PI%202%20%7C%20Raspberry%20Pi%20%7C%20XDA%20Forums&txt=http%3A%2F%2Fgo.microsoft.com%2Ffwlink%2Fp%2F%3FLinkId%3D526740) that provides you with `dism.exe`
- Only check `Deployment Tools` - You don't need any thing else.
- Default directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\x86\DISM`

Open a command prompt with Admin Privileges

- Run `diskpart`

  - `list disk` (check the disk number your SD card is on)
  - `exit`
- Windows 7,8 - Go to the ADK Directory. Windows 10 can just type dism.(In windows 7,8 there is also `dism.exe` but it is the old version and wont work, you must go into the ADK Directory)
- Copy the `flash.ffu` to the ADK directory where dism is for simplicity.

> dism.exe /Apply-Image /ImageFile:flash.ffu
>   /ApplyDrive:\.\PhysicalDrive **{DIRVENUMBER FROM DISKPART}**
>   /SkipPlatformCheck

On my machine it was disk 2 (Notice PhysicalDrive2)

```
dism.exe /Apply-Image /ImageFile:flash.ffu /ApplyDrive:\\.\PhysicalDrive2 /SkipPlatformCheck
```

You will see a progress bar while the image is applied. Once it is complete put the SD card into your Raspberry Pi 2, hook up Ethernet and HDMI. Boot up.

On the first boot make sure you dont have any extra peripherals installed just in case, for best power optimization. You will see the Windows Logo, some Blue screen and then a reboot. The screen may be blank up to 3 minutes in some places so be patient.

[image]

- Username: administrator
- Password: p@ssw0rd
- [You can find some PowerShell help here, which will help you connect to Pindows](https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/PowerShell.htm)
- You can connect via your browser by typing in the IP or `miniwinpc`
- There seems to be miracast installed by default but I could start it from the WebGUI.
- There are allot more ideas and samples [here](https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/StartCoding.htm) and [here](https://microsoft.hackster.io/)

[* Source](https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/SetupRPI.htm)

Comment: You can also SSH in using putty in windows or SSH client in Linux , to get administrative console.

Answer (score 2):

At this point there's no experimental builds, and both the RPi foundation and MS have been fairly closed mouth about the entire thing.  I'm betting that we won't see it until early 2016 since the normal desktop/tablet version is expected sometime around the end of this year (though no official dates have been released).

**Edit:**

According to this [interview](http://www.raspberrypi.org/the-raspberry-pi-guy-interviews-eben-and-gordon/), the Windows 10 release will be available "later this year", and will be geared primarily towards IOT applications.

Comment: I think it will be sooner than that but people should beware the pi version will **not** have a GUI.

Comment: It wont have a GUI.. but it will be able to render graphics or GUI's to a LCD using DirectX and Windows 10 API. +this question is not the same as mine.