# Functions and limitations of Windows 10 IOT for Pi 2

Tags: windows-iot

I and a lot of others are confused with the win 10 os. I want to know if the os has a full gui web surfing and video, standalone exe runnable functionality like raspbian and ubuntu mate. I mean as a consumer os on common sense like windows 7, 8 or 8.1, Mac os x, etc.  couldn't find enough information on google. Can it be used as a separate operating system like the many linux oses?

Comment: Install the preview and play around with it - http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/32185/894

Answer (score 3):

Please bear in mind that the current version is only a technical preview, so it's not yet clear how the final version will look like. At the moment, there is no explorer shipped with the system - and as this is one of the most integral parts of the Windows operating system, a lot of people therefore consider the IoT version as "not a real Windows".

It's however not true that it doesn't have a graphical user interface. The default screen that will show up after starting the system is actually a regular Windows Universal app that mostly consists of XAML and C# code. It is therefore easy to create additional applications with a "real" user interface to run them on Windows IoT.

I would even say that chances are good that we will see the explorer in not such a distance future on the IoT platform. I'm taking that guess because there is already an ARM version of the explorer which was released together with the first and second generation of the Surface (not the Pro edition). That version could maybe run easily on the IoT version as well, I however hardly doubt that the performance would be acceptable at the moment (maybe a reason why they didn't include it).

To sum that up and return to your question: No, it's not a "consumer" operating system that wants to compete with Mac os, Ubuntu or the other Windows editions. It's designed for the Internet of Things and will therefore never provide all that comfort that you are used from the consumer oriented operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

No it does not.

Win 10 IoT for the Raspi is for embedded use only - so you do not get a desktop and desktop apps.

Even if a desktop etc are eventually released for it, you still won't be able to run "standard" x86 apps

Comment: Please remove your signature block, as this is not customary on SE sites.  You may place such information on your user page.

Comment: was not aware of sig restrictions